# Server time and browser time are not corresponding using ISO

Tags: javascript, node.js

Title says it pretty much, I'm trying to check how many seconds have been passed since the last update from the server using `Date` but it is not working as expected.

**Date sent by server**

```
var startedAt = new Date().toISOString();
```

**Date from browser**

```
currentTime = new Date().toISOString();
```

Browser gets the signal pretty much immediately after the date is sent by the server so their should not be any big difference, tho these are the outputs;

```
started at 2018-03-22T23:15:26.823Z
currently at 2018-03-22T23:15:00.406Z
```

When I calculate the difference in `ms` I get `26417ms`.

What should I be doing instead, this obviously doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Unless you're running everything from localhost, your server and your browser are different computers. Naturally their clocks are different.

Comment: That's either a very slow network transmission, or a missing NTP synchronisation on either of the two computers.

Comment: @Vince yeah, I figured but it is such a random difference, any way I could convert both Dates to the same timezone, eg UTC?

Comment: @Bergi there's barely any delay, idk what the NTP sync is about though.

Comment: Even if they're both the same timezone their times will be different. It's just like setting the time two regular, old-fashioned, clocks. There's no reliable way to get them both to be exactly the same time. Especially when the calculation is as fine-grained as `ms`.

I'd say your best bet is to do the entire calculation client-side (in the browser) then send the result back to the server as an asynchronous request.

Comment: NTP is [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) and you can't count on it being set up anywhere.

Comment: @OrpheuZ They're out of sync by 26s, which is normal if they are not synced using NTP. They *are* in the same time zone.

Comment: @OrpheuZ What do you mean by "random"? Does the time difference fluctuate a lot?

Comment: @Bergi no rather just an odd number.